# Vue JS computed property freezes when filtering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a filtering system with a search field as part of a development project I'm working on. A user can type something into the search field and it will in real-time filter an array of objects for a matching value.

My problem, is that I have 3,000+ objects in my Array, each object contains about 6 key, value pairs. It's an array of cars.

It's being pulled from Vuex, and the computed property checks when someone types in a value into the field.

Every time I begin typing, there is a pause whilst it filters the array of objects for matching values...

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      search: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getCars() {
      return this.$store.state.localStorage.cars
    },
    filteredCars: function() {
      return this.getCars.filter(car => {
        if (car.car != null) {
          return car.car.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        } else {
          return car
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I thought computed properties work quickly? I also tried using https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed#usage-example, but this doesn't solve the issue either.

Comment: Use a method instead of a computed getter here. Make sure the method has a `debouncer` that wraps it.

Comment: This doesn't work. I am outputting my `filteredCars` property in a `v-for` to the page, it's something that happens in real-time, a method seems unreasonable, and actually a method doesn't run on load, and I need it to. Furthermore, changing this to a method and using loadash debouncer fails to execute.

Comment: Is the filter function working as expected? I didn't understand why you are doing `return car` at the end of the filter. Shouldn't you only return when the `includes()` part returns true?

For calling a method on load, you can always do `this.methodName()` in the `created()` part of componenet

Comment: Are you sure that it's the computed property that's being slow here? It seems more likely the problem would be any subsequent rendering that uses the array it returns. Try adding `.slice(0, 10)` after the filtering so that it just renders the first 10 cars. That may not be the behaviour you want but it would help to establish where the problem lies. Generally I wouldn't expect to be able to render an array with 3000+ entries without some form of lazy rendering.

Comment: Totally not true. 1. A method can run on page load, call it in your `created()` hook. 2. Using a debouncer would not cause a method to fail to run, either, but bad implementation would.

Comment: Have you tried to log the call _before_ and _after_ to check the times and to see if the methods is called more than once ?